# content isn't moving with the div in chrome only (issuewith asp control)

Tags: asp.net, css, google-chrome, positioning

I have a menu div that appears just fine in IE9 and Firefox, but in chrome and IE8, the contents of the div are not following actual div itself when the div is moved:

IE9/FF:
[image]

Chrome:
[image]

As far as I can tell, i don't have any css conflicts or issues with flow. I may be missing something though (obviously). Any help would be greatly appreciated. TIA

Here is the current div hiearchy:

```
<div id="mainBody">
     <div id="mainMenu" class="mainMenu">
          <asp:Menu class="menuItems">
               <--- menu items jargon here --->
          </asp:Menu>
     </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
body
{
    background-color: #E7EDEB;
}

.textBox
{
    margin: 1px;
}
#mainBody
{
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Calibri;
    letter-spacing: .03em;
}
.mainMenu
{
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    background-color: White;
    margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    left: 50px;
    bottom: 25px;
    height: 30px;
}
.MenuItems
{
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: large;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: left;
    color: #000000;
    margin: 3px;
}
div#mainContent
{
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 1000px
}
```

UPDATE:
I removed the asp menu control from the div and replaced it with plain text. It looked much more like you would expect, so it's leading me to believe it has something to do with the control itself. I haven't applied any styles to the control itself so im still lost.

Comment: Can you show us the actual HTML instead of the ASP tags?

Comment: @Sinaesthetic: Can you provide a preview page so we can see what the dealio is? Thanks!

Comment: @j08691 I'm not sure what you're asking for. It's an asp page, the divs are the only html in there. The only thing contained in this div is an asp menu control. I only put that in as a placeholder so you can see the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being an ASP control issues, I didn't think I'd ever figure it out. It turns out that it WAS an issue with the way ASP was rendering the control. Thanks to Rob, we were able to narrow it down to a SkipLink. Since the page is personal, I don't need to worry about skiplinks so I opted to disable it completely. The way to do it in ASP is simply to set SkipLinkText to "" in the menu control.

For anyone else that comes across this, there are a few other tricks shown here:

http://forums.asp.net/t/976796.aspx/1

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Try adding styling to your skiplink:

```
#ctl04_SkipLink {
position:absolute;
left:-9999px;
}
```

Comment: #ct104_SkipLink seems to be a link reference, not an object. I see what you're trying to do but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

It's caused by your hidden anchor before the ul. Haven't figured out why yet.

EDIT: Actually, it appears its your hidden image inside that anchor.

Comment: I didn't explicitly place any ul or hidden images, it must be what's being rendered from asp. As I added to my OP, i removed the control and replaced it with plain text and it came out more like you would expect. It would seem that this is more of an ASP question now :((

Comment: @Sinaesthetic Well, setting the image with the alt "Skip Navigation Links" to 'display:none' makes the problem go away.

Comment: did you do that by hand? How the heck do i change that in visual studio?

Comment: @Sinaesthetic Haven't a clue. I would never use asp for anything and don't use VS. I tested it using developer tools in Chrome and Firebug in Firefox.

Comment: Yeah, i see the hidden image in the rendered source. I can't for the life of me find what is placing it there. Must be something the control is using... argh

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
top:0;
```

to .mainMenu and reload it a few times ;)